# mysql FIND_IN_SET not working with php variable with integer values

Tags: php, mysql, set

I'm struggling with this issue.

I have in mysql a SET field fk_item_types with (10,20,30,40,50,60) values.

I have a php variable $itemtype that i use to filter records with the fk_item_types.

The problem I have is that the filter is not working when I use the variable as filtering value, but it works when I write the value.

```
"WHERE FIND_IN_SET('30',fk_i_item_type)>0" works ok.
```

this doesn't work:

```
"WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$item_type',fk_i_item_type)>0"
"WHERE FIND_IN_SET('{$item_type}',fk_i_item_type)>0"
"WHERE FIND_IN_SET('" . $item_type . "',fk_i_item_type)>0"
```

using $itype = (string) $item_type doesn't work either.

Using the "LIKE '% %' " alternative doesn't work either.

I appreciate your help.

B/R.

Comment: Hi this is the resulting sql with the variable SELECT * FROM (oc_t_item_custom_attr_fields) WHERE FIND_IN_SET('30',fk_i_item_type)>0

Answer (score 0):

Your var fk_item_types looks like this ?

```
SET @fk_item_types = '10,20,30,40,50,60';
```

And add an @ before your variable name in the request.

Also, var_dump your variable `$item_type`, just in case.